# When is System.Drawing.Bitmap not System.Drawing.Bitmap?

Tags: c#, winforms

While shooting a memory expansion problem, I ran into an anomaly that has me stumped.

```
using (var theImage = ApplicationGlobalWinForm.Properties.Resources.LanguageIcon) {
    PictureBox1.Image = theImage;
    this.Icon = System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(theImage.GetHicon());
}
```

where

- `ApplicationGlobalWinForm.Properties.Resources.LanguageIcon`is a resource resident image, which loads as a`System.Drawing.Bitmap`
- `this.Icon`is the application's window's icon
- `PictureBox1`is a client-area image
- the`using`is part of my hunt for that memory expansion problem
- the application is a WinForms (rather than WPF) application, as noted in this post's tags

*After the method that holds the above code has completed*, the application suffers "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll".

Moving the`PictureBox1.Image`assignment deeper into the code and assigning to it`theIcon.ToBitmap()`instead of`theImage`fixes things:

```
using (var theImage = ApplicationGlobalWinForm.Properties.Resources.LanguageIcon) {
    var theIcon = System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(theImage.GetHicon());
    this.Icon = theIcon;
    PictureBox1.Image = theIcon.ToBitmap();
}
```

Given that both`theImage`and`theIcon.ToBitmap`are of the same type (`System.Drawing.Bitmap`), what's going on?

A further puzzlement is that removing the`using` from the problematic code snippet

```
var theImage = ApplicationGlobalWinForm.Properties.Resources.LanguageIcon;
PictureBox1.Image = theImage;
this.Icon = System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(theImage.GetHicon());
```

works just fine, thank you.

I'm stumped (and I haven't killed that memory expansion problem, either) and hope there's some WinForms maven out there who can explain things.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but here's what I think is happening.

In the first example you're assigning theImage to `PictureBox1.Image`, setting `this.Icon` to a new icon created from `theImage` (but no longer references `theImage`), then disposing of `theImage` (leaving the `using` block). So now `PictureBox1.Image` refers to something that is disposed so when a paint event or something similar happens it blows up.

In the second example you create a new icon from `theImage` (again, no longer referencing `theImage`), setting `this.Icon` to the icon created in the previous step, then setting `PictureBox1.Image` to a new bitmap made from the icon, and finally you dispose of `theImage` but since nothing is using it anymore it doesn't matter.
I bet if you call `PictureBox1.Image.Dispose()` you'll have a similar result as you did in the first code sample. That would also explain why removing the using statement makes everything work again.

Comment: Thank you ... good thinking ... I will try and post the results.
Best!
[I still haven't nailed the culprit for the memory expansion, either.]